# No core dump generated with C++ app using oracle db [RHEL]

Tags: c++, oracle11g, rhel5

I have a c++ application (using MySQL/Oracle) built on RHEL 5.6 box

core dumps have been enabled 
`ulimit -c unlimited`

When the application uses Oracle db and triggers a SIGSEGV signal, no core dump is generated.

Whereas, using MySQL a proper core dump is generated with the exact same steps.

Any headers on what might be wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use the same executable both with Oracle and MySQL? Or they are different and either of those has the SETUID/SETGID bits on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21572816/836215 or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci10new.htm#CHDCIAHJ