# Oracle Instant Client 12 - How to disable 'Fault Diagnosability' (SIGTERM issue)

Tags: oracle, signals, oracle12c, oracle-call-interface

It seems I am suffering from this issue: [Oracle Pro*C/OCI install handlers for SIGSEGV/SIGABRT and friends - why, and how to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124881/oracle-proc-oci-install-handlers-for-sigsegv-sigabrt-and-friends-why-and-how)

The answers in that question suggest that I create a `sqlnet.ora` file and put the following content into it (possibly only the second line would be enough - but I am not sure):

```
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=OFF
DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=FALSE
DIAG_DDE_ENABLED=FALSE
```

I am currently using the [Oracle Instant Client Version 12.2.0.1.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) downloaded from Oracle.

Currently the Oracle Instant Client is installed under `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/` (which contains the folders `bin/`, `lib/` and `network/`). `ORACLE_HOME` is also set and points to `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/`.

When I place the above three lines into `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/network/admin/sqlnet.ora` they seem to have no effect. I tried starting my application additionally with `TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/network/admin` which also had no effect. Finally I tried to put an `sqlnet.ora` into the local folder from where I start my application and then started it with `TNS_ADMIN=. ./myapp`, which also had no effect.

How can I disable the **Fault Diagnosability** of the Oracle Instant Client in order to get back control over Unix signals in my app.