# Stucked while preparing an sql request pro*c

Tags: sql, c, oracle, prepared-statement, oracle-pro-c

I have a binary that I generated from a program written in C language and that stucks in this line of code:

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE x FROM: y;
```

with `'y'` is a  simple selection request:

```
select count(distinct id_appli) FROM APPLICATION WHERE id_appli = '2' ;
```

could you tell me the cause of such a problem ?

PS : I'm working on AIX
Sometimes I got a core file, when I used gdb command I got this result :

```
core: AIX core file fulldump 32-bit,

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xd482acac in skgesig_sigactionHandler ()
   from /produits/oracle/db/11.2.0.2/lib32/libclntsh.so
(gdb) where
#0  0xd482acac in skgesig_sigactionHandler ()
   from /produits/oracle/db/11.2.0.2/lib32/libclntsh.so
#1  <signal handler called>
```

Comment: Which database/embedded language?

Comment: Any error message you are receiving?

Comment: Oracle 11.2.0.2/C language

Comment: @ErayBalkanli : No I don't get any error message

Comment: I added some details in my request message above

Comment: Need to see the actual code where you declare and assign `y` and execute the prepare statement.

Comment: Run the program in gdb debugger to find out more. Also it would be useful to disable Oracle's signal-handlers, see the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124881/oracle-proc-oci-install-handlers-for-sigsegv-sigabrt-and-friends-why-and-how

Comment: I think you have to SELECT INTO some host variable previously DECLAREd.